# Python error: " 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

I'm using some code given to me by a professor, and don't have the knowledge to figure this out. 
I get the error:

```
 26 err=(x0-2.)
 ---> 27 rate_est=abs(err[1:-1]/err[0:-2])
 28 print('The estimate of our convergence rate is:', rate_est)

 TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

In case it is useful to you, here is the other related code:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np

 def g(S,x):
     g=(1/2)*((S/x)+x)
     return g;

 x0=1
 S=2
 tol=pow(10.0,-10)
 stopCrit=1.0
 deltaX=1.0
 nIter=0
 xn=x0
 print(x0)
 while((stopCrit>tol) and (nIter<50)):
     nIter=nIter+1
     x1=g(S,x0)
     xn=np.append(xn,x1)
     print(x1)
     deltaX=np.abs(x1-x0)
     stopCrit=deltaX/np.abs(x1)
     x0=x1
 xn=np.array(xn)

 err=(x0-2.)
 rate_est=abs(err[1:-1]/err[0:-2])
 print('The estimate of our convergence rate is:', rate_est)
```

Comment: You can't index into a float. You probably want to index into an array. `xn` looks like an (the only?) array in your code so maybe you want to do `err=(xn-2.)` instead but it is hard to say without understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Is the lack of whitespace meant to punish the reader for their sins?

Answer (score 0):

Your `err=(x0-2.)` is a float. In the following statement you're treating it as a list or tuple or something: `err[1:-1]/err[0:-2]`, which does not make any sense.